# Arduino optimisation for a college project

Tags: optimization, arduino

My friend is running a project in his college and has no clue about UML and code optimisation - I have no clue about Ardunio's.

This is his "UML" that he provided me with, could anyone help with optimising this, so he can code it properly. I'm a C++ coder, so I know that this many if statements is stupid, so can someone help with turning this `if` chaos into a useable format?

```
If - Gyro = outputting
then - Timer = start
If - Timer = on
then - Every 30 seconds
check - gyro = outputting
If - Timer = 5 minutes
Then - Transmitter = on
Else - Timer = reset
If - Transmitter = on
Then - LED = on
If battery = low
Then - LED = on
```

Thanks

P.S Sorry if I'm not explaining myself well haha

Comment: What happened when you tried to just code this in C/C++?

Comment: I haven't yet, let me have a pop

Comment: this pretty much describes the task and so far is not an overly complicated task for an arduino processor.  You just have to decide on the sandbox/libraries you want to use (or not program the part directly), and then work through each of these items.  Lots of learning, dont see any need for optimization here, just implementation.

Comment: Ugh, my VS isn't on this computer - I'll download it in a min.

Comment: See my issue with his UML is that it's going to look a bit horrid when he comes to document it, and wanted to know if Arduino has a better way to run a statement like this

Comment: how exactly is this *"UML"*?

Comment: It's a keyword thrown in by his lecturer haha